# Required attribute 'select' is missing is coming on executing build.xml file using Ant

Tags: selenium, xslt, ant, testng

I want to generate XSLT Report in Selenium.
Build.xml file with section to add XSLT report target to produce XSLT report is as below:

```
target name="makexsltreports" depends="">
<delete dir="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output">
</delete>
<mkdir dir="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output"/>
<xsltin="$(ProjectDirectory)/testoutput/testngresults.xml"style="$(ProjectDirectory)/testng-results.xsl"
out="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html">
<paramname="testNgXslt.outputDir"expression="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
<param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
<param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />
<param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS"name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />
```

On running build.xml with ant , build is not getting successful as error coming that "Required attribute 'select' is missing ".

So please anybody correct me where I am getting wrong from the above code lines so that I can generate XSLT reports with selenium.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some white space between xml tag names and their attributes. There are also some unclosed tags. Does this help?

```
<target name="makexsltreports" depends="" />
<delete dir="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output" />
<mkdir dir="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output" />
<xslt in="$(ProjectDirectory)/testoutput/testngresults.xml" style="$(ProjectDirectory)/testng-results.xsl" out="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" />
<param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="$(ProjectDirectory)/XSLT_Reports/output/" />
<param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
<param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />
<param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As in provided information, not mentioned using SaxonLiaison or not. below the target i am using and working pretty well

```
  <target name="makexsltreports">
        <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

        <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="${ws.home}/testng-results.xsl"
              out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
            <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
            <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
```

I cam across this [blog](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/01/xslt-generate-interactive-reports-on.html) with all step by step details if required.

Thank You,
Murali